# R: Creating a new row based on previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, row

I'm new to R and trying to create a new row based on values on previous rows.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.table(Item = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 "2010FY" = c(3, 5, 2, 2),
                 "2011FY" = c(5, 6, 2, 1),
                 "2012FY" = c(-1, 2, 2, 0.5))
```

I would like to create a new row that divides the 3rd row by the 4th row. Let's call this Item "e" and ideally should like this:

```
    Item     2010FY     2011FY     2012FY
1     a        3          5          -1
2     b        5          6           2
3     c        2          2           2
4     d        2          1          0.5
5     e        1          2           4
```

Using dplyr, my first attempt is:

```
 df <- bind_rows(df, e = df[Item %in% "c", ] / df[Item %in% "d", ])
```

This does not work because characters are not divisible (ie. The Item column).

I found that the function mutate_if would work but only by column. Is there a way I can do this by row?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure `dplyr` is really well suited to this sort of operation, as it tends to operate on whole columns rather than rows and subsets. You could probably do it outside a pipe using similar operations to what you are doing - `rbind(df, c(Item="e", df[df$Item == "c", -1] / df[df$Item == "d", -1]))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works! I assume that the -1 ignores the first column Item to perform the calculations on numeric columns only?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: FYI, you can answer your own question. This helps users with similar issue quickly find a solution!

Comment: Will do! Thank for letting me know

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments above, this worked:

```
rbind(df, c(Item="e", df[df$Item == "c", -1] / df[df$Item == "d", -1]))
```